# windows 10 changes clipboard data automatically

Tags: windows, clipboard

I came across below situation, what I did was ,

1. Copied a url using Ctrl + C  (`http://stackoverflow.com/users/123456/user`)
2. Made a new text file and clicked rename.
3. Pasted that url using Ctrl + V to rename it.
4. It gave an error that it can't change the file name to a name with /
   and : ....
5. It removed / and : automatically and set the file name.(`httpstackoverflow.comusers123456user`)
6. Then I opened the text file and pressed Ctrl + V again to paste the
   url into the file ,
7. Surprisingly the clipboard value has changed , to below as an example.

`http://stackoverflow.com/users/123456/user`

to

`httpstackoverflow.comusers123456user`

Why did this happen ? any ideas? I'm Using windows 10 anniversary Update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I can reproduce this phenomenon. There is a [free clipboard viewer](http://www.freeclipboardviewer.com/windowsclipboard.html) that let you see what is happened:

- first it shows a link "https://stackoverflow.com/users/123456/user":

[image]

- now you try to use this string as a file name
- at the moment when the error message will shown, you see that the content of the clipboard has been changed to "httpstackoverflow.comusers123456user":

[image]

This changes has been made by windows explorer that removes the "wrong" ASCII characters from the string. 
The important point here is, that we get the content of clipboard ***by reference*** (and not by value as a copy), that is why a change is possible!

[EDITED]

- Question:  can you explain "by reference and not by value" a bit more ?

There are [two ways to pass the parameters in programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value): by value and by reference.

[image]

When a parameter is passed by reference, **the caller and the callee use the same variable** for the parameter. If the callee modifies the parameter variable, the effect is visible to the caller's variable.

When a parameter is passed **by value**, **the caller and callee have two independent variables with the same value**. If the callee modifies the parameter variable, the effect is not visible to the caller.

The windows clipboard can have a huge content: pictures, text and so on. That is why it is better to **copy just an address of this memory block** instead of copy of the whole content.